# GQL how to select by UserProperty

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

Hey I have this code but it doesn't work because it is expecting a string. How can I make it work?

```
class Atable(BaseModel):
    owner = db.UserProperty()
        (...)

--------- // --------------
query = "SELECT * FROM Atable WHERE owner=", users.get_current_user()
results = db.GqlQuery(query)
```

How can I fix that search? 
Thanks :)

I've started with the appengine database yesterday so be gentle :)

Comment: If someone can fix the question tittle to a more descriptive tittle, it would be great :)

Comment: I think that your question's title is just fine

Comment: Please, please, please don't assemble GQL strings with string concatenation. We don't need GQL injection vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
query = GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Atable WHERE owner = :1", users.get_current_user())
```

Comment: No, just "WHERE owner = :1" - adding USER will make it expect a string.

Answer (score 3):

You could try the GQL way:

```
results = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Atable WHERE owner = :1", users.get_current_user().key())
```

or the Python Query way:

```
query = db.Query(Atable)
results = query.filter('owner =', users.get_current_user())
```

Answer (score 0):

The python query way is probably easier if you just need to get some data for that user.

For example in your class Something(db.Model), you can define:

```
@staticmethod
def get_something_by_user(user):

        query = db.Query(Something).filter('users =', user)
        result = query.fetch(limit=1000)

        return result
```

Then you call it by doing this:

```
user = users.GetCurrentUser()
results = Something.get_something_by_user(user)
```